# How to print the keys that hold a certain value in my nested dict?

Tags: python

I have this dictionary and I want to print the names of the keys that have the diet carnivore and the keys that are 4 years old. But when I run my code nothing happens.. How can I get the keys?

My code:

```
pets = { 'Dog': {'name': 'Rex', 'age': 4, 'diet': 'carnivore', 'gray':False },
     'Cat': {'name': 'Betty', 'age': 10, 'diet': 'carnivore', 'gray':True },
     'Rabbit': {'name': 'Simon', 'age': 4, 'diet': 'herbivore', 'gray': True},
     'Fish': {'name': 'Fluffy', 'age': 1, 'diet': 'herbivore', 'gray': False}}
            

for key, value in pets.items():
if 'carnivore' in value:
     print(key)
if 4 in value:
     print(key)
```

Expected output:

Dog

Cat

And:

Dog

Rabbit

Comment: Presumably you want `if value['diet']=='carnivore':`

Comment: `{k for k,v in pets.items() if 'carnivore' in v['diet']=='carnivore'}`

Comment: `value` is a dict. `in` with dicts checks for the existence of *keys*, not values. And why would you want to check *all* values instead of specific ones like `diet` and `age`?

Comment: You say *diet carnivore AND the keys that are 4 years old* with that constraint it would only be Rex who is a carnivore AND 4 years old. You really me OR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nested `dict`, so the loop body must be a little more complex:

```
for key, dct in pets.items():
    if 'carnivore' in dct.values():
        print(key)
    if 4 in dct.values():
        print(key)
```

Of course, making a contains-check on the values is not ideal for a `dict` if you know the keys that you expect to be bound to the value:

```
for key, dct in pets.items():
    if dct.get('diet') == 'carnivore':
        print(key)
    if dct.get('age') == 4:
        print(key)
```

Comment: For this particular data structure, I'm not sure why you'd even use `get` instead of `[]`.

Comment: It might be a sample. Some keys might be missing from some of the dicts.

Comment: Then I'd switch to `get` if and when that becomes necessary, but not as the default.

Comment: I'll leave it as it is as this point is not really relevant to the OP'S issue. But generally I'd agree to see an error first before losening assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

```
pets = {
    'Dog': {
        'name': 'Rex', 'age': 4,
        'diet': 'carnivore', 'gray':False },
    'Cat': {
        'name': 'Betty', 'age': 10,
        'diet': 'carnivore', 'gray':True },
    'Rabbit': {
        'name': 'Simon', 'age': 4,
        'diet': 'herbivore', 'gray': True},
    'Fish': {
        'name': 'Fluffy', 'age': 1,
        'diet': 'herbivore', 'gray': False}
    }
            

for key in pets:
    if pets[key]['diet'] == 'carnivore':
        print(key)


for key in pets:
    if pets[key]['age'] == 4:
        print(key)
```

Comment: Why the needlessly complicated `pets[key]` instead of using `pets.items()`?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose you can do that but for such a simple case this should do the job. Moreover, it looks more intuitive to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for key, value in pets.items():
    if value.get('diet') == 'carnivore':
        print(key)
for key, value in pets.items():
    if value.get('age') == 4:
        print(key)
```

**Output** :

```
Dog
Cat
Dog
Rabbit
```